# UITextView in UITableViewCell scrolling problems

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextview

Ok. I have made a custom cell for my table, and it contains a text view. When I have multiple lines in the text view, I can scroll up and down, but in doing this the table also scrolls. How can I stop this behaviour? If anyone needs parts of my code or further details, please just ask. I am more than willing.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just to clarify:
I have custom controllers, no `touchesBegan` etc, and I need it to be editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to move text edit (write) behavior to another view controller. If you need read-only functionality from it then just increase cell and textView height.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting `canCancelContentTouches` to NO?  It's a property of UIScrollView, from which UITableView inherits.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom cell seems to pass on touch events to its container class as well as utilizing them itself. Did you implement any `- touchesBegan:`, `- touchesMoved:` or `- touchesEnded:`?

If you make use of a touch events, you should not pass them on in the responder chain.

Comment: Thanks for trying though. I just managed to answer a post thinking it was about the iPhone, when in fact it was about Mac. Easily done ;)

Comment: True, I edited it accordingly (@jrtc27: Saw that, and commented there, too ;) )

Answer (score 0):

When the text view has focus, set `scrollEnabled=NO` on the table view.  You may have to manually remove focus from the text view and restore scrolling when a touch occurs outside the text view.